# Inadvertantly removed auto-renewable subscription from sale. Now all subscrptions are being cancelled.

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscription, cancellation, auto-renewing

We have an iOS app in the app store with two auto renewing subscriptions. A weekly with a week free subscription (lets call it A) and a monthly with a month free (Lets call it B). In the last release of the app we added a third subscription a monthly with increased price and reduced free period (Lets call it C).

After the release the weekly (A) and the old monthly subscription (B) were removed from sale (just removed from sale, not deleted). Nothing unexpected happened for a couple of weeks, then we started receiving large quantity of subscription cancellations from the weekly (A) and monthly (B) subscribers. The new monthly (C) subscribers are unaffected. I immediately moved the A and B subscriptions back to 'Available' in iTunes connect, however the cancellations are still coming in.

Is there anything I can do to stop the flood of cancellations, and possibly restore the previous cancellations back to active subscriptions?

As background info, all these subscriptions are for the same service. We've just being experimenting with different billing, free trial periods and pricing.

Comment: I'm sorry for that but I'm afraid there is nothing to do. For sure you can't restore it by yourself. To stop it, try to mitigate to source of cancelation, if it is really because of your mistake or not

Comment: @GIJOW I suspected as much. The cancellation rate is something like 100x our normal rate, and its definitely our mistake causing this. I'm still shocked that there are no warnings on un-checking the 'cleared for sale' checkbox about affecting existing subscribers. A (very expensive) lesson learned.